# Obtener la cantidad maxima para cada registro en consulta sql

Tags: sql

trabajo en sql server 2000 y estoy haciendo una consulta a una tabla "personas",
que tiene muchos registros duplicados, no tiene clave primaria, es decir por cada vez que una persona se ingreso al sistema tiene un registro con una edad diferente(la que tenia al momento de registrarse), quiero obtener solo un registro por cada persona, el ultimo que tenga,o sea el de mayor edad, pero al usar MAX toma el maximo de toda la tabla no de cada persona:

```
select distinct nombre,apellido,max(edad) from persona
```

eso es lo que tengo.

Answer (score 5):

Te aconsejaría que leyeras la documentación de las funciones de agregación en SQL Server (como `MAX`, por ejemplo). De todas formas, lo que necesitas es:

```
SELECT nombre, apellido, MAX(edad) edad
FROM persona
GROUP BY nombre, apellido;
```

Answer (score 1):

> quiero obtener solo un registro por cada persona, el ultimo que
>   tenga,o sea el de mayor edad

Creo que es suficiente usando la función [MAX()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx):

```
SELECT nombre, apellido, MAX(edad) edad FROM persona GROUP BY nombre, apellido;
```

y es necesario `GROUP BY nombre, apellido;` para poder realizarlo, de lo contrario obtendrías el siguiente error:

> is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

(como yo lo tuve al no agregarlo en mi respuesta inicial =( ).